# data exchange between components react typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In general, the task is simple. I want to transfer data from state Child.tsx in the state of the parent component Parent.tsx
I'm a little confused about it. Help me figure it out, please.
At the time of rendering in the Child.tsx already has todos, at least 3 because I use localstorage. And they are not displayed in Parent.tsx

---

**Parent.tsx**

```
const [todosChild, setTodosChild] = useState<ITodo[]>([])

let getTodos = (todos: ITodo[]) => {
    setTodosChild(todos);
}
console.log(todosChild); // []

<TodosPage create={getTodos} />
```

**Child.tsx**

```
interface TodosPageProps {
    create(todos: ITodo[]): void;
}

export const TodosPage: React.FC<TodosPageProps> = ({ create }) => {

  const getTodos = (todos: ITodo[]) => {
     return create;
  }

  const [todos, setTodos] = useState<ITodo[]>([])

}
```

**ITodo.ts**

```
 export interface ITodo {
  title: string
  body: string
  id: number
  completed: boolean
 }
```

Comment: Can you tell us more about what you are trying to do and what you expect to see? Right now none of the components is rendering anything onto the page. Another question is, you said "At the time of rendering in the Child.tsx already has todos" but where is the code for initiating those todos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it would be nice to see how u are calling `getTodos` in the child component, btw if you are just calling it once like `getTodos(todos)` it won't work since you are not really calling the function `create`:

```js
const getTodos = (todos: ITodo[]) => {
  return create; // <-- Not called
}
```

So you will need to call the create function inside the `getTodos` one:

```js
const getTodos = (todos: ITodo[]) => {
  return create(todos); // <-- Now its called
}
```